# No ThemeDictionaries for ResourceDictionary in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

No ThemeDictionaries in ResourceDictionary. It is a normal WPF project. Wondering what is necessary to enable ThemeDictionaries. Do I have to import any library? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2017. The project was created from **New Project -> Visual C# -> WPF App(.Net Framework)**.

[image: picture]

Comment: I'm not sure, but think that ThemeDictionaries are available only for UWP projects, not for WPF Desktop Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ThemeDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.themedictionaries) property is specific to UWP.

There is no such property available in WPF. You could create different themes yourself by simply defining several ResourceDictionaries that contain the same keys.